# How typing rtk reducer in root module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I am writing a react application using a modular architecture. Each module is imported outside a single interface.

```
const authModule: IModule = {
routes,
reducers: {},
};

export type IModule = {
routes?: IRoute[]
reducers:IReducers
};
```

Then all modules are collected into one in the root module:

```
const modules:IModule[] = [
  authModule,
  userModule,
  weatherForecastModule,
  commonModule,
];

const routs = modules.reduce(
  (acc: IRoute[], module) => (!module.routes ? acc : [...acc, ...module.routes]),
  [],
);
const reducers = modules.reduce(
  (acc: IReducers, module) => ({ ...acc, ...module.reducers }),
  {},
);

const rootModule: IModule = {
  routes: routs,
  reducers,
};

export default rootModule;
```

From which I add all reducers to the store:

```
const store = configureStore({
 reducer: {
   [baseApi.reducerPath]: baseApi.reducer,
   ...rootModule.reducers,
   userReducer,
   screenReducer,
 },
 middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware()
   .concat(baseApi.middleware),
 devTools: true,
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);

export default store;
```

In the process of assembling reducers into one module, their typing is lost, which is why useAppSelector does not show possible reducers

```
const user = useAppSelector((state) => state.???);
```

Additional info:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppStore = typeof store;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch'];

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

How fix it?

Simple example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wilbur-qj27hs?file=/src/modules/user/index.ts

Comment: How did you type the `useAppSelector`? Show the code

Comment: What are `IRoute`, `IModule` and `IReducers` types?  Try create a running demo using https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @NaumZakletskiy Please make code additions by editing the question instead of posting code in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You will not get around manually assembling the type for the resulting object.
There is no way for TypeScript to infer this in any way, considering that your cast to `IModule` already removes all "interesting" type information from them.

Comment: In short, he should use type inference.

Comment: Even then, they would have to write a *monster* of a generic type to mash all of it together, and types could easily get lost when putting things into arrays.